# ifelse() only evaluating for matching rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with a special column `a`. This column can be either numbers, or a SPECIAL value that tells me to look at column `b`.

```
foo <- tibble(
  a=c("15", "20", "SPECIAL", "13"),
  b=c(NA, NA, 32, NA)
)
```

It would be great if I can transform this using `dplyr`

```
foo %>%
  mutate(
    a=ifelse(a == "SPECIAL",
             b,
             as.numeric(a)
      )
  )
```

Looks good, reads well. Unfortunately, `ifelse(test, yes, no)` evaluates both the `yes` and `no` arguments. And of course, `as.numeric(a)` gives a warning for `SPECIAL`.

Is there any alternative for `ifelse`, that can automatically split a data.frame first? I want to avoid evaluating `as.numeric(a)`

*Note: Edit to make the problem more clear*

Answer (score 1):

`tidyr::separate` would work here

```
foo <- tibble(
  a=c("15", "20", "3x10", "13")
)

foo %>%
  separate(a, into = c("a", "new_col"), sep = "x")

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  a     new_col
  <chr> <chr>  
1 15    NA     
2 20    NA     
3 3     10     
4 13    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(strsplit(foo$a, "x"), function(x) {prod(as.numeric(x))})
```

---

in `dplyr::` syntax:

```
foo %>%
    mutate( a = sapply(strsplit(a, "x"), function(x) {prod(as.numeric(x))}) )

# A tibble: 4 x 1
#      a
#  <dbl>
#1    15
#2    20
#3    30
#4    13
```